# Service on Big Sur to start Terminal doesn't work with Finder, works with other apps

Tags: terminal, mac, finder, automator, shortcut

I picked up a new MacBook recently and started customizing it software-wise.

After some research, I have managed to set a shortcut for opening Terminal as follows:

1. Open Automator
2. Select New Document, Quick Action, search „Launch Application“ and drag it over
3. Select the desired application (may be located in „others“)
4. Select File->Save in the menu bar
5. Open System Preferences and select Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services
6. Provide a shortcut for the Quick Action. In my case, I have selected <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Sadly, the shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> doesn't work when the Finder is the active app. With any other app, it works.

I don't understand why, as the shortcut isn't assigned to any action in the Finder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You write `I have managed to set a shortcut for opening the Terminal`, how have you done it?  Is it an Automator Quick Action configured as a service?

Comment: Step by step: Open Automator on Mac - select new document, quick action - search „Launch Application“ and drag it over - select the desired application (may located in „others“) - select file->Save on the menus bar — now open the system preferences and select keyboard->shortcuts->services - your quick action should now be visible in the list, you just need to provide a shortcut for it

Comment: That sounds OK, which shortcut did you choose?

Comment: @jaume I used cmd ctrl T quite similar to how I used it with Linux

Comment: [Mac keyboard shortcuts > Finder and system shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236#finder): "Control-Command-T: Add the selected item to the sidebar (OS X Mavericks or later)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is default shortcut which may interfere: [Mac keyboard shortcuts > Finder and system shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236#finder):

> Control-Command-T: Add the selected item to the sidebar (OS X
> Mavericks or later).